# How to merge to arrays saving their keys?

Tags: php, arrays

Want to merge

```
array(
 2 => 'a'
 3 => 'b'
);
```

and

```
array(
 7 => 'c'
 9 => 'd'
);
```

to get

```
array(
 2 => 'a'
 3 => 'b'
 7 => 'c'
 9 => 'd'
);
```

`array_merge()` gives me

```
array(
 0 => 'a'
 1 => 'b'
 2 => 'c'
 3 => 'd'
);
```

Comment: what if two arrays have same keys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simple you can do like this-

```
$result = $array1 + $array2;
```

Simple exapmle

```
$array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
$array2 = array(1 => 'one_b', 3 => 'three_b', 4 => 'four_b');
$result = $array1 + $array2;
var_dump($result);
```

Output

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "zero_a"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "two_a"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "three_a"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "one_b"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "four_b"
}
```

Comment: what if two arrays have same keys?

Comment: @BhavikShah It will remove the second array value and hold just the first value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add arrays: `$myArray1 + $myArray2;`

Comment: I know that it will remove the second element with the same key and that will be a problem. Isnt it?

Comment: @BhavikShah I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

use the array unison operator: "+"

```
<?php

$foo = array(
 2 => 'a',
 3 => 'b'
);

$bar = array(
 7 => 'c',
 9 => 'd'
);

$result = $foo + $bar;

print_r( $result );
```

Answer (score 0):

$array1 + $array2;

is my choice and it works well.